# Deploying Java Servlet applications on Windows with IIS

Tags: iis, war

I have develop JSP-Servlert application (i.e. WAR file) which running perfectly on tomcat server. Now I want to run same web application on IIS without tomcat.

Currently I am following this url: http://www.helicontech.com/articles/deploying-java-servlet-applications-on-windows-with-iis/

But while configuring Java hosting package as per mentioned in the above article, it is giving error to download jetty 8. Other softwares from the same package is getting download and install successfully.

When I checked the logs, I found that it is downloading the jetty from the URL: "http://dist.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-hightide-8.1.7/jetty-hightide-8.1.7.v20120910.zip" and all the codehaus services has shutdown.

Can anyone help me to install the jetty into IIS or any other option to deploy the WAR into IIS?

Thanks, 
SameerK

Answer (score 3):

Definately the easiest option, at the time of writing, is to use [Microsoft's HttpPlatformHandler](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/httpplatformhandler) that you can install on IIS 8+ (Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012 at least).

You basically need to:

1. Install IIS on your machine
2. Install JDK
3. Install Jetty on Windows (just download zip and unpack it)
4. Create WAR file
5. Copy WAR file to your Jetty's installation folder under webapps directory.
6. Set up IIS web site with web.config as described [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/httpplatformhandler/httpplatformhandler-configuration-reference).
7. That's it. You can view your site using http://localhost:your_iis_defined_port/your_war_name. If you rename your WAR to root.war then 'your_war_name' will not be necessary.

I have prepared a [step by step guide](http://itmeze.com/2015/08/23/deploying-clojurejava-based-web-app-via-jetty-on-windows-and-iis-step-by-step-guide) on how to do that with more explanation.

Comment: broken link ... step by step guide

Comment: Step by step guide is working. But here's a Wayback Machine permanent link for it:
https://web.archive.org/web/20190914124419/https://itmeze.com/2015/08/23/deploying-clojurejava-based-web-app-via-jetty-on-windows-and-iis-step-by-step-guide/

Answer (score 1):

After hours of trying i managed it by adding a ReverseProxy Rule, this is fairly easy and done super fast.

I had these dependencies installed already: AAR and HttpProxyHandler